# WebRTC Audio Is completely garbled

Tags: browser, cross-browser, webrtc

Check it out here:

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/

All the audio recording sounds like aliens trying to communicate with you. I could of swore WebRTC was working just last week but this site of samples is completely freaking out on both my laptop and my phone.

Does anyone know why the audio is freaking out like that?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why is it freaking is the audio freaking out like that?

Comment: nothing freaking on my lap.

Comment: I'm getting insane reverb. I don't understand what is causing it since I have no audio playing or headsets nearby

Comment: Have you tried updating your web browsers? Seems to be working fine on `Chrome 45.0.2454.99 dev-m` and `Chrome 47.0.2508.0 dev-m`. Did you check your microphone input or test it elsewhere (on both devices)?

Comment: Looks like if I turn the volume down and set it to "speakerphone" it chills out a little but it's still surprisingly sensitive. Way to sensitive to use for a real product.